# Remove First Filed in Array and insert MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have one array  i want insert mysql database.

```
Array ( [posts] => Array ( [0] => 
Array ( [channel_id] => 18560 [category_id] => 41 [channel_name] => Bohemian FC 1 - 1 Chelsea [channel_image] => IMG-20190416-WA0087.jpg [channel_url] => nourl [channel_description] => [channel_type] => URL [video_id] => [category_name] => Last day Matches ) [1] => 
Array ( [channel_id] => 18559 [category_id] => 41 [channel_name] => Nigeria 2 - 1 South Africa [channel_image] => IMG-20190416-WA0087.jpg [channel_url] => nourl [channel_description] => [channel_type] => URL [video_id] => [category_name] => Last day Matches ) ) ) 
Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( )
```

insert.php

```php
foreach($array as $row) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
{
    $query .= "INSERT INTO tbl_channel(category_id,channel_name,    channel_image,channel_url,channel_description,channel_type,video_id) VALUES ('".$row["category_id"]."', '".$row["channel_name"]."', '".$row["channel_image"]."', '".$row["channel_url"]."', '".$row["channel_description"]."', '".$row["channel_type"]."', '".$row["video_id"]."'); ";  // Make Multiple Insert Query 
    table_data .= '<tr></tr>'; 
}
if(mysqli_query($connect, $query)) //Run Mutliple Insert Query
{    
    echo '<h3>Imported Data</h3><br />'; 
}
```

I cant Insert values in MySQL Table.  I Have Getting Error `Illegal string offset 'category_id'` what Error My Code(Sorry bad Language )

Comment: You also can't run multiple queries within the same `mysqli_query()` call.

Comment: Also note the SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Although you need to fix the way you insert the data (prepared statements and run once for each row), looks as though you also need to fix your loop as there is a level of array in there you are missing - `foreach($array['posts'] as $row)`

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop that builds the query string, add a quick check to see if the correct array elements exist, and only add them to the query string if they do.

```
if (isset($row['category_id'])) {
   // add the row to the query string
  }
```

Then as @Qirel said, you can't run more than one query, so you need to call `mysqli_multi_query()` instead.

Also as @Qirel noted, this kind of thing is an ideal place to use prepared statements. Prepare the query before the loop, then call it with the different parameter values inside the loop. It adds a level of security against vulnerability and maybe a small performance increase.